# Java: Parentheses matching unsure of how to produce correct error outputs

Tags: java, algorithm, string-matching, parentheses

so I have revised my code as other said (after actually looking at an algorithm for this problem) and my solution is now working! However I must now print out error messages. I have done the error message if say you have the input: "{ } < )" it will return that ) does not match < but I must also notify that opening brackets remain unclosed and closing brackets do not have a corresponding opening bracket. I am unsure of how to do this with my current implementation. Any help would be great!
Thanks, Kyle.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.EmptyStackException; 
import java.util.Stack; //using java's default stack in this case as it has more     extraneous error checking

    public class Question3 {
private static final String OPEN = "([{<";
private static final String CLOSED = ")]}>";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader inKb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter a test string:");
    String input = inKb.readLine().replaceAll(" ", "");

    System.out.print(parChecker(input));
    // System.out.println(successful);
}

private static boolean isOpen(char ch) {
    return OPEN.indexOf(ch) >= 0;
}

private static boolean isClosed(char ch) {
    return CLOSED.indexOf(ch) >= 0;
}

private static boolean matches(char open, char close) {
    int openIndex = OPEN.indexOf(open);
    int closeIndex = CLOSED.indexOf(close);

    return (openIndex == closeIndex);
}

public static boolean parChecker(String input) {
    boolean balanced = true; // is stack balanced (matching parentheses)
    boolean ret = false; // return value

    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() && balanced; i++) { // if it's not
                                                            // balanced stop
                                                            // searching

        char bracket = input.charAt(i);
        if (isOpen(bracket)) {
            stack.push(bracket);
        } else if (stack.isEmpty())
            balanced = false;

        else {
            char top = stack.pop();
            if (matches(top, bracket) == false) {
                System.out.println("Error: '" + bracket
                        + "' does not match with '" + top + "'.");
                balanced = false;

            }
        }
    }
    if (balanced && stack.isEmpty()) {
        System.out
                .println("The string is correct! There are no mismatched brackets");
        ret = true;
    } else
        ret = false;

    return ret;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to keep track of all open brackets in their order of appearance, and keep that state up to date.

Comment: How should I go about doing this? Should i perhaps keep a seperate stack of all closing brackets that did not match?